# Geo nodes: realizing instances loses uv maps / texture

Tags: materials, uv, export, geometry-nodes, instances

*System: RTX 3080,  Ryzen 5 3600,  16GB RAM,  Windows 10*

**Disclaimer: I am very new to blender.**

Hi everyone!

My main goal is to export the LEGO version of my model with the correct colors (as shown in the second picture). I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrEHoaq6QFE) tutorial but are yet to find a way to export the model nor give it the right colors. The youtube guy said you need to realize the instances before you can export them, so I used the "realize instance" node right before the end. When I place that, I lose the UV Maps / textures of the model. I have tried placing the realize instance in every place imaginable, but to no avail. Screenshots below so you know what I am talking about!

Thank you for any help!
-Jack

**How it looks after realizing instances**

[image: How it looks after realizing instances]

**How it should look**

[image: How it should look]

**Shading nodes**

[image: Shading nodes]

**Geo nodes after adding realize instance**

[image: Geo nodes after adding realize instance]

Comment: Do you mean the sentence "_If you want to be able to export models, the instances must be realized, and some of the settings in the node tree need to be changed to use geometry instead of instances_" in the video description? Did you change anything to **use geometry instead of instances** like he said? Doesn't look like it... I have no time to build the nodetree right now, but I would suspect that maybe the Store Named Attribute node should be switched to something else than _Instance_, and in the shader I could imagine you should switch from _Instancer_ to _Geometry_ as well...

Comment: yes I tried to switch around the node settings but to no avail. If you have any ideas on what to do please let me know!